# how crypto-js hide the class method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, methods, cryptojs

Start With This

```
import crypto from 'crypto-js'
global.crypto = crypto
```

When I Access crypto from the browser Console I got the following error

```
crypto['AES'].encrypt('MyString', 'pass').toString() // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined(…)
```

but when I access it from Node it works -_-

```
crypto['AES'].encrypt('MyString','pass').toString() // Encrypted String
```

How Crypto JS do this? can't directly access from the browser, but accessible in node?

Comment: What was the error you received, specifically? It will aid people in answering your question.

Comment: the error is
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined(…)`

Comment: Did you use anything to transform the `import` statement into something the browser can use, such as ? Because [import isn't natively supported yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: Yes, I did. I use babelify to compile it.

Comment: Also check whether `crypto` is `undefined`.

Comment: It wasn't undefined. crypto variable return a Function, named "Crypto"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that 'crypto' is reserved internally by the window object. Try importing under another name.

Comment: Whoooaa~ Thank you for answering my question! Your Right!
I think, I should say goodbye to my project since there is no way to hide the class method :(